# In a Rails form, how does one create <button>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

More specifically, I need to create `<button type="submit">Foo</button>` type markup in my Rails form. Is there a helper for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, you could obviously do in HTML, or

```
<%= content_tag(:button, "Foo", :type=>:submit)%>
```

But if you want to do the following then check out [Rails Button Tag](http://github.com/panpainter/Rails-Button-Tag) :

```
<%= button_tag "Foo"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= submit_tag "Foo" %>
```

Here is the documentation for rails form helpers [ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

Comment: Actually that creates the following markup: <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="commit">

Comment: So you want the button outside of a form? Or, why would you want a button tag, does it have semantic meaning?

Comment: nope, I want the button inside of the form, exactly how it is above. I could use just regular HTML, but was wondering if Rails had a facility also for doing this.